# Intermediate Dynamic Equation of Motion

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics

If I were to determine the equations of motion for a symmetric top that is both spinning and allowed to translate in a single horizontal direction via its contact point.

How would I determine the equation of motion for the system by determining the moment about its contact point. I am having trouble with the fact that the point I am taking moments about is both spinning and translating.

I am trying to determine the equation of motion for the system pertaining to its moment about the contact point, not its center of mass.

I know if the top were fixed, then the moment about the contact point would be equal to the time derivative of its angular momentum which is the moment of inertia about the contact point times the top's angular velocity.

I know I am not accounting for a term in the equation of motion that pertains to the fact that the contact point is not fixed in inertial frame nor is it the top's center of mass.

How can I determine the system's moment about its translating contact point more appropriately than just saying the moments about contact is equal to the time derivative of the angular momentum? I know I need something to account for the fact that the point is translating with the body and is not fixed in space.

Comment: You could use a moving coordinate system. Just transfer all forces and moments acting on the moving points into this moving coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the object is translating along the x-axis with a velocity of

$v$ and rotating about the contact point $O$ with an angular velocity$\overrightarrow{\omega} $.

First off for a stationary contact point $O$ that we assume is the origin, the equation of motion of any point distanced, L, from the origin $o$ is

$$x=L*cos(\omega t)$$
$$Y=L*sin(\omega t)$$

In the case of a translating origin the $$Y2=Y1$$

$$X_2=X1+v*t=L *cos(\omega t)+v*t$$
The angular momentum doesn't change for the system if there is only constant speed and no additional torque is added along the way.